# Programmatically rewriting slug through functions.php but returns 404

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, slug, single

I wanted to change the slug of a certain post type (in this case, **article**) into whatever a certain value in its custom field.

I went to *functions.php* and put this code.

```
function na_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

if ( 'article' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
    return $post_link;
} 

# get the custom field value here to be the slug
$post_name = get_field('filter_category', $post->ID)->post_name; 
# replace the "article" by the value of the custom field
$post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', "/$post_name/", $post_link ); 
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'na_remove_slug', 10, 3 );
```

When I query the custom post types, it appears as if its slug was altered, for example:
**www.example.com/article/some-title** into  **www.example.com/design/some-title**

Where **design** is my custom field value.

But when I finally visit **www.example.com/design/some-title**, I get a 404. But if I visit **www.example.com/article/some-title**, it returns the correct web page.

I understand that my code only changes how the link appears when it is displayed, but how can I show my single post correctly using the slug that I have altered?

If you need more clarification, please don't hesitate to comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/), I think this will work for you. You can directly change the URL on your page by clicking on URL to whatever you want.

Hope this would be helpfull.

Comment: Hi Baikare! I already have that plugin. But unfortunately, I need to do the URL rewriting programmatically, as I have existing posts already. It will be too much if I rewrite all of them individually. Thank you though!